# Simple slidetoggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I am new to JS and learning it now. I was trying to achieve simple accordion with toggleclass and toggleslide but I can't figure out what is causing my code not to run!

```
<div class="outer-wrapper collapse">
    <div class="inner-wrapper1">title 1</div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper2">
        something written
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer-wrapper collapse">
    <div class="inner-wrapper1">title 1</div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper2">
        something written
    </div>         
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.inner-wrapper1').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("collapse expand"); 
    $(this).parents('div.outer-wrapper').find('.inner-wrapper2').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

CSS:

```
.outer-wrapper.collapse .inner-wrapper2 {
    display :none;
}
.outer-wrapper.expand .inner-wrapper2 {
    display :block;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser console? Also, your second div block is missing some closing div tags.

Comment: I don't get any error but I am not getting expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an extra class for show it. `SlideToggle` does it itself.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper1">title 1</div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper2 hide">
        something written
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide { display: none }
```

JS:

```
$('.inner-wrapper1').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().find('.inner-wrapper2').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/d42cfxcb/

### Update

Well you can simplify more -

html

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div>title 1</div>
    <div>something written</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var $accordion = $('.outer-wrapper');

$accordion.each(function(){
    // or you can do this with CSS using hide class- .hide { display: none }
    $(this).children('div:eq(1)').hide();
});

$accordion.children('div:eq(0)').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('div:eq(1)').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/d42cfxcb/1/